# How i can set the Cookie 'fe_typo_user' ?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3 6.2.9.

If i Logged a User with PHP, then the Content does not display.

I think it coheres with the Cookie fe_typo_user. But I don't know how i can set this Cookie.

Some wrote in an other Question this. [Typo3 Extbase losing fe_user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398653/typo3-extbase-losing-fe-user-authentication/29214259#29214259)

Please Help, and sorry about my bad english

Comment: very vague question. What content does not display?  The cookie will be set by TYPO3 itself if you, fx, use the fe_login box. Or do you need to set it yourself with a login form you create yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->loginSessionStarted = true;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
```

This is my PHP Code to log a User in. But the Content for this User, doesn't displayed...

When i check it the User Logged In with '$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user', return 'true'. So the Content would have to displayed.